# Generate associative arrays SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

How can I generate many associative arrays in SystemVerilog with the generate statement?

e.x.

Here is one associative array declaration

```
logic [8-1:0] memory [*];
```

How do I generate 10 of them without writing them manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use a generate statement. You can have arrays of arrays

```
logic [8-1:0] memory [10][int];
```

P.S. I strongly recommend that use never use `[*]` as an index type and instead use `[int]` or some other existing data type. `[*]` is there for backward compatibility with an older language and using it prevents you from accessing the full power of SystemVerilog.

Comment: No [*]? I wasn't aware of that. Why's that?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor, You can't use foreach, or any other array method that needs an index type (first,last, find_index, etc.) when using a wildcard index. See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/associative-array#reply-56713